# Append a string before a return

Tags: php, wordpress

I need to add a string (Category:) before the slug in this function :

```
remove_filter( 'sanitize_title', 'sanitize_title_with_dashes' );
add_filter( 'sanitize_title', 'wpse5029_sanitize_title_with_dashes' );

function wpse5029_sanitize_title_with_dashes($title) {
    $title = strip_tags($title);
    // Preserve escaped octets.
    $title = preg_replace('|%([a-fA-F0-9][a-fA-F0-9])|', '---$1---', $title);
    // Remove percent signs that are not part of an octet.
    $title = str_replace('%', '', $title);
    // Restore octets.
    $title = preg_replace('|---([a-fA-F0-9][a-fA-F0-9])---|', '%$1', $title);

    $title = remove_accents($title);
    if (seems_utf8($title)) {
        //if (function_exists('mb_strtolower')) {
        //    $title = mb_strtolower($title, 'UTF-8');
        //}
        $title = utf8_uri_encode($title, 200);
    }

    //$title = strtolower($title);
    $title = preg_replace('/&.+?;/', '', $title); // kill entities
    $title = str_replace('.', '-', $title);
    // Keep upper-case chars too!
    $title = preg_replace('/[^%a-zA-Z0-9 _-]/', '', $title);
    $title = preg_replace('/\s+/', '_', $title);
    $title = preg_replace('|-+|', '_', $title);
    $title = trim($title, '-');

    return $title;
}
```

I tried :

```
return "Category:".$title;
```

but it didn't work, it return just "Category:"

Comment: `return "Category:".$title;` is correct. If it just returned `Category:`, it means that `$tile` is empty.

Comment: If i remove "Category:" the title shows correctly

Comment: Then there must have been some other change as well when you tested it: https://3v4l.org/Yk6dY. You need to do more debugging since the syntax is correct.

Comment: Your code is correct syntax wise, so i tested it on my own blog, it works as intended on my end. So with wordpress, usually there are third party themes and/or plugins involved. These third party themes and plugins often run their own functions with high priority. So to test this please try to give your custom filter a high priority, let's say, `999` to make sure your filter runs after all of the cusome functions have run. `add_filter( 'sanitize_title', 'wpse5029_sanitize_title_with_dashes' , 999);`

Comment: I tried to change priority to 999 but it didnt work. The function work correctly until i add `Category:` to `$title` in `return`

Comment: I added `return "Category:".$title;` and it works fine on my blog.

Comment: My filter is exactly like the code in the question.

Comment: There is no need to call it. Its called on every Title update.